# Terminal floats between desktops

Tags: macos, terminal, bug

On my mac, OS X Yosemite, if I have terminal open and multiple desktops the terminal window appears on all desktops. How do I disable this feature and have the terminal stick to the desktop it was launched on or dragged to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control or right clicking the dock icon should allow you to pin the app to a specific desktop.

Comment: Perfect solution!